# How to redirect users to a defined play store experiments variant?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Is it possible for a campaign to force redirect a user to a defined play store experiments variant that we have made?

Comment: You mean ,forcefully redirect to play store link?

Comment: @Kabir yes but with a custom store listing